# JavaFX troubles with removing items from ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, javafx, bufferedwriter

I have 2 `TableView`s (`tableProduct`, `tableProduct2`). The first one is populated by database, the second one is populated with selected by user items from first one (`addMeal` method, which also converts those to simple `ArrayList`). After adding/deleting few objects user can save current data from second Table to txt file. It seems to work just fine at beginning. But problem starts to show a bit randomly... I add few items, save it, delete few items, save it, everything is fine. Then after few actions like that, one last object stays in txt file, even though the `TableView` is empty. I just can't do anything to remove it and I get no errors...

Any ideas what's going on?

```
 public void addMeal() {
    productData selection = tableProduct.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (selection != null) {
        tableProduct2.getItems().add(new productData(selection.getName() + "(" + Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText()) + "g)", String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getKcal())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getProtein())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getCarb())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getFat())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100))));
        productlist.add(new productSimpleData(selection.getName() + "(" + Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText()) + "g)", String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getKcal())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getProtein())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getCarb())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getFat())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100))));
    }
    updateSummary();
    }


public void deleteMeal() {
    productData selection = tableProduct2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if(selection != null){
        tableProduct2.getItems().remove(selection);
        Iterator<productSimpleData> iterator = productlist.iterator();

                    productSimpleData psd = iterator.next();
                    if(psd.getName().equals(String.valueOf(selection.getName()))) {
                        iterator.remove();
                }

    }
    updateSummary();
}

public void save() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Maciek\\Desktop\\test1.txt");
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }
    FileWriter fw = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(file);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        Iterator iterator;
        iterator = productlist.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            productSimpleData pd;
            pd = (productSimpleData) iterator.next();
            bw.write(pd.toString());
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

and yeah, I realize `addMethod` inside `if` statement looks scary but don't mind it, that part is allright after all...

Comment: One likely source is the `getName()` methods on `productData` and `productSimpleData`. You don't supply the code for this, but from the creation code in `addMeal()` it looks like your original name is concatenated with the `Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())` result to create a new name. This could be returning different results on each call so the names/objects you think should be equal aren't. Try using an integer identifier on the objects, or separate the name and weight fields. (Class names should also adhere to conventions, e.g. `ProductData`, `ProductSimpleData`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever check the first item in the `productlist` list to determine, if the item should be removed. Since you do not seem to write to the `List` anywhere without doing a similar modification to the `items` of `tableProduct2`, you can just do the same in this case.

```
public void deleteMeal() {
    int selectedIndex = tableProduct2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

    if(selectedIndex >= 0) {
        tableProduct2.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        productlist.remove(selectedIndex);
    }
    updateSummary();
}
```

This way you also prevent issues, if there are 2 equal items in the list, which could lead to the first one being deleted when the second one is selected...

---

> and yeah, I realize `addMethod` [...] looks scary

Yes, it does, so it's time to rewrite this:

Change the properties in `productData` and `productSimpleData` to `float` and don't convert the data to `String` until you need it as `String`.

```
if (selection != null) {
    float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText());
    float weight100 = weight / 100;

    float calories = Float.parseFloat(selection.getKcal())*weight100;
    float protein = Float.parseFloat(selection.getProtein())*weight100;
    float carb = Float.parseFloat(selection.getCarb())*weight100;
    float fat = Float.parseFloat(selection.getFat())*weight100;

    ProductData product = new productData(
                               selection.getName() + "(" + weight + "g)",
                               calories,
                               protein,
                               carb,
                               fat);
    productlist.add(new productSimpleData(product.getName(), calories, protein, carb, fat));
    tableProduct2.getItems().add(product);
}
```

Also that this kind of loop can be rewritten to an enhanced for loop:

```
Iterator iterator;
iterator = productlist.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    productSimpleData pd;
    pd = (productSimpleData) iterator.next();
    bw.write(pd.toString());
    bw.newLine();
}
```

Assuming you've declared `productlist` as `List<productSimpleData>` or a subtype, you can just do

```
for (productSimpleData pd : productlist) {
    bw.write(pd.toString());
    bw.newLine();
}
```

furthermore you could rely on a `try-with-resources` to close the writers for you:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)){
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also there is no need to delete the file since java overwrites the file by default and only appends data if you specify this in an additional constructor parameter for `FileWriter`.